# cypreess to get browser logs for specific page

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, spy

I have been working on a Cypress project for 2 months. My next task is to get the browser logs.

Let's imagine this page is the one I need to test for the moment:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Home page
        </h1>
        <script>
            console.log ("log test");
            console.warn("warn test");
            console.warn("warn test2");
            console.error ("console error");
            console.error ("console error 2222");
            console.info("info test");
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

once this page is loaded there will be 6 logs. we can see it by opening inspect window.

I want to get each log count in the cypress code:

```js
      it('should not greater than the previous error log count', () => {
    
               const allLogs = getlogs(); // get all the broswer logs.
               const previousCount = getPreviousValueFromExcel() // this method already implemented
               const erroLogCount = // filter allLogs and get only console.error count
    
            
        })
```

I have no access to the UI code. so I can't change it. only I have access to the automation code

**Method 1**

```
it('should not greater than the previous error log count', () => {
  cy.visit('/foo', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      // Stub your functions here
      cy.stub(win.console, 'error').as('consoleError');
    }
  });
  const previousCount = 2;
  cy.get('@consoleError').should('have.length', previousCount) 
})
```

that approach also not working. every time I run the test it always returns 0.
[image]

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566283/9884190

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I have no access to the UI code. so I can't change it. only I have access to the automation code

Comment: It should work whether you have access to the UI code. Cypress is launching an electron app & embedding the browser in the app's window...therefore we should have access to the browser logs. Have you try using this code within the `it` block?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal
No it's not working

Comment: You will need to update your answer to include screenshots, code added, logs, error messages, etc...

Comment: @ManuelAbascal It only catch the console log inside the  "it" block not the page logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Cypress spy on multiple calls of the same method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73588146/16997707)

```js
it('should not greater than the previous error log count', () => {
  cy.visit('/foo', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      cy.spy(win.console, 'error').as('consoleError')
    }
  });
  const previousCount = 2;

  cy.get('@consoleError')
    .its('callCount')
    .should('eq', previousCount)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use `cy.spy` to spy on the `console.log` functions.](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-spy-on-console-log)

```
it('should not greater than the previous error log count', () => {
  cy.visit('/foo', {
    onBeforeLoad(win) {
      // Stub your functions here
      cy.stub(win.console, 'error').as('consoleError');
    }
  });
  const previousCount = getPreviousValueFromExcel();
  cy.get('@consoleError').should('have.length', previousCount) // or however you are determining the expected error count.
})
```

Comment: it always returns 0 - " assertexpected [Function: consoleError] to have a length of 2 but got 0 "

Comment: Ah, what if you use `have.callCount` instead of `have.length`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply., I update the description. can you please check?  I tried you answer but it failed and I added Screenshot of the Error

Comment: Did you also try using `have.callCount` instead of `have.length`? The screenshot still has `have.length`.

Comment: In here we check the exact count.  do you know way to check if the log count is less than the given number

Comment: `cy.get('@consoleError').its('length').should('be.lessThan', previousCount);` might work.